# in commerce, how to assign child to a parent product

Tags: commerce

Is it possible to create a parent product that will contains all basic informations for a product  (Product title, Product Descriptions) and attach this parent product to children product (Sku, Color, Size, Price)

for the moment, the only solution I found is to create all the children at first and than create a Parent Product node with Product reference field pointed on child product where I can choose many childs.

Is it possible to do the oposite. I would like to create all the parent product first and assign ONE parent product to a child product during the child creation process. That's mean, I would like to have a dropdown with all the parent in there.

Thanks a lot

Comment: How would you indicate the "candidate" parent products, so that you would now which products are allowed to be assigned as the parent product?